# ListView take dimension of child

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

Like the title, I'm trying to put some elements inside `ListView` with some height and width (taken dynamically), so I don't want hardcode the dimension for ListView.
Are there any methods to be able to set the height of `ListView` as the height of its child?

```dart
class HomepageScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(22),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  // OTHER WIDGETS
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 80,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: rectangles.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  CustomRectangle rectangle = rectangles[index];
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => print('detailed'),
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                      child: RectangleWidget(
                        color: rectangle.color,
                        height: rectangle.height,
                        width: rectangle.width,
                        title: rectangle.title,
                        subtitle: rectangle.subtitle,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I find is creating a method that returns a double:

#### METHOD

```dart
  double getHeightOfRectangle(List<CustomRectangle> rectangles) {
    if (rectangles.isNotEmpty) {
      return rectangles.map((e) => e.height).reduce(max);
    }
    return 80.0;
  }
```

#### USING METHOD

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(22),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  // OTHER WIDGETS
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: getHeightOfRectangle(rectangles),
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: rectangles.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  CustomRectangle rectangle = rectangles[index];
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => print('detailed'),
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                      child: RectangleWidget(
                        color: rectangle.color,
                        height: rectangle.height,
                        width: rectangle.width,
                        title: rectangle.title,
                        subtitle: rectangle.subtitle,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you're looking for with `shrinkWrap: true`, you can change this behavior so that the ListView only occupies the space it needs (it will still scroll when there more items).

In your case would end up being something like this:

```
class HomepageScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(22),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  // OTHER WIDGETS
                ],
              ),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              //Apparently only works on a vertical scroll direction
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: rectangles.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                CustomRectangle rectangle = rectangles[index];
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => print('detailed'),
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    child: RectangleWidget(
                      color: rectangle.color,
                      height: rectangle.height,
                      width: rectangle.width,
                      title: rectangle.title,
                      subtitle: rectangle.subtitle,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Already tried, but in that case, I'm getting this error: `'constraints.hasBoundedHeight': is not true.` It seems that the `ListView` doesn't take the height of child

Comment: @Shifenis So I tried your code and indeed is not working, it only works if the scroll direction is `vertical`, but since yours is `horizontal` the only way I got it to work was with a Expanded or Flexible widget wrapping the ListView, but don't really know if that suits your needs.

Comment: In this case, `Expanded` or `Flexible` is not fit me cause in this way the `ListView` takes all height that it can take, instead to take the height of its child. Probably I'll to create some method that iterates to each element of the list and gets the height. This is the only solution that I have